# Scrape tweets using API in python

Tags: python, twitter, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape searching results using twitter api. After each request, the program will sleep 60 seconds and continue. But the problem is that the results of two requests are nearly the same. How to avoid this?

Comment: Check if Twitter API sends [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

Comment: Even better, use the streaming APIs. Specifically for your case you should use the [Public Streams API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public). "Suitable for following specific users or topics, and __data mining__."

Comment: If we don't know your request and request logic, it is hard to see what your problem is. But it seems you are running the exact same query, and people just don't use yojr search term much? Instead of re-searching, use a streaming API!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below link to get the tweets.

https://github.com/anandstarz/Scrapee/blob/master/tweets